# Populate array with objects attributes of an object literal

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I have some cards defined as objects within an object, e.g:

```
var cards = {
    s2: {suit: 4, rank: 2, name: '2 of spades'},
    s3: {suit: 4, rank: 3, name: '3 of spades'},
    //etc. 
};
```

I need them to be within an object, not an array.

I then need to create an array of certain length and populate it with cards.

Something along these lines:

```
var cardDeck = [];
for (i=0; i < 52, i++){
    cardDeck.push(???);
}
```

I tried to use for in loop and play with keys and even managed to push objects, but only {key} worked for me, unfortunately giving object containing only key value. How do I get whole objects pushed into cardDeck array?

Answer (score 2):

you almost had, it, just loop through the objects by their keys, get each object from the key, and push it into the array

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q3jaagcq/

```
var cards = {
    s2: {suit: 4, rank: 2, name: '2 of spades'},
    s3: {suit: 4, rank: 3, name: '3 of spades'},
    //etc. 
}; 

var cardDeck = [];

for (var key in cards) {
    var card = cards[key];
    cardDeck.push(card);
}

console.log(cardDeck);
```